# Select random option and do function

Tags: javascript, html-select

I'm working on a  menu. I would like the menu to always pick a random option.

```
 <select id="textFont">
 <option value="A"></option>
 <option value="B"></option>
 <option value="C"></option>
 </select>

 var $options = $('#textFont').find('option'),
 var random = ~~(Math.random() * $options.length);
 $options.eq(random).prop('selected', true);

 document.getElementById("wrapper").style.fontFamily=random;
```

the above code is working pretty good, now to the thing. I would like this random value to go into the last function the one that changes the font-family of #wrapper. But I'm getting a number of the options array when I alert('random'). Is there away to see what the value of 1 to 3 = ('A','B', 'C') and output it to the last function?

ex:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.fontFamily='A';
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.fontFamily='C';
```

Comment: `var random = ~~(Math.random() * $options.length);` - whats up with that double squiggly?

Comment: @tymeJV: That's shorthand (/a hack) for `Math.floor()`

Comment: @Cerbrus -- Learning something new every day (I assumed with all the pretty quotes it was something off)

Comment: @Cerbrus No, it's not. [Bitwiese operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) convert a number into a integer. It works for small numbers, just like `num|0`. But it fails if the number is too large to fit into an integer (`~~9007199254740992.1` = 0 but `Math.floor(9007199254740992.1)` = 9007199254740992).

Comment: @dusky: Fair point, but for small enough numbers (in this case `<3`) it gives the same result as `Math.floor()`. E.g. `~~900723456.740992 == 900723456`. Not say that I think it's good practice to use it. It's not. Also worth noting, for numbers `<0` it behaves differently than `Math.floor`. It actually becomes equivalent to `Math.ceil`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.fontFamily = $options[random].value;
```

Comment: exactly — adding  "'" + $options[random].value; "'"; thanks again for helping out!

Comment: @duplex: why are you adding quotes? You shouldn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgdeL935/))

```
function selectRandom() {

    // The dropdown list
    $selectList = $('#textFont option');

    // Amount of options in it
    var options = $selectList.length;

    // Random number between 1 and the amount of options
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * options) + 1);

    // Select the option based in the random number
    $selectList.eq(random).prop('selected', true);
}
```

and call the function in your document.ready() function to load a random option every time someone refresh the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    selectRandom();
});
```